# retrieving cell value in a column that is in list and conditioned on another column

Tags: pandas, list, cell

I need to locate the page no where the word 'their' appears.
on that same page I need to retrieve 'text' that is in list ['slightly', 'tiny bit','somewhat', 'rather']. Hence the output here be just 'slightly'.

words table:

| page no | text | font |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | they | 0 |
| 1 | ate | 0 |
| 1 | apples | 0 |
| 2 | and | 0 |
| 2 | then | 1 |
| 2 | their | 0 |
| 2 | stomach | 0 |
| 2 | felt | 1 |
| 2 | slightly | 0 |
| 2 | painful | 1 |
| 2 | given | 0 |
| 2 | the | 1 |
| 3 | fruit | 0 |

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should allow you to get all pages that have "their" then from those that have "their" the text that also is in the list of words you are targeting

```
target_list = ['slightly', 'tiny bit','somewhat', 'rather']
df.loc[(df['page no'] == df.loc[df['text'].str.contains('their')]['page no'].squeeze()) & (df['text'].isin(target_list))]
```

Comment: ArchAngelPwn ..thank you for that, working really well now!!